# Magento jQuery themes

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, prototypejs

Is there such a thing as "jQuery" themes for Magento? Why are developers still writing themes in prototype?

Here are my concerns:

- Themes rely rather heavily on the framework so much that so that without JS enabled (or indeed, if there's a bug which breaks JS), you can't add to basket, you can't checkout... that's bad, really, really bad.
- Last update to prototype was 2012. It's not developed any more. We've just had to fix a bug where a Firefox update has broken a page. If it's not being developed in line with browser updates, it's self-destructive.

And yet all I see is themes written with prototype, which is just plain stupid. Someone please show me where the jQuery themes are.

Comment: Magento development is conservative and has tended to stick with older frameworks and php releases. May not be what you're looking for, but like our ERP system, they tend to be 1-2 OS versions behind on what they support. Those who try to jQuerify Magento fetch up on this rock. Magento 2.0 is supposed to cure all this. Tis the nature of the beast many have tied their fortune to.

Comment: FYI, PrototypeJS is being developed as evidenced by the github repo https://github.com/sstephenson/prototype and there is a release that should be out by end of April 2014.

Answer (score 1):

If jQuery had come out sooner it would have probably have been in Magento, but it wasn't and prototype was a more well established framework at the time.

You can use jQuery with Magento if you really want to by using noConflict mode of jquery.  If you absolutley need it.  For the most part prototype works just fine, and there isn't always a reason to load 2 javascript frameworks into your site at a time.

I highly recommend http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/ if you're just looking to execute a few simple things.